# Google Maps Polygon Representation

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, heatmap

I used google maps to make a project that records flood incident in a certain area. I used polygons to represent those floods, since the project is for planning purposes it is required of us to output all the historical flood data into a single map.  My problem is if I simply just output all polygons, it would look messy and cluttered.  So I was wondering what method I could use to represent these polygons in a better fashion. We were advised to use heatmaps, but I can't seem to find tutorials on how to make polygons into heatmaps. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To turn a polygon into a heatmap, render the polygons in black with high transparency into a white bitmap. This should result in a grayscale image, which will be darker where many polygons overlap. Then convert the gray values of the bitmap into the hue value of a corresponding semi-transparent color bitmap.

Why did the rendering look messy? Did you try rendering filled polygons with high transparency and no borderline? That should result in areas that are more prone to flooding being more "highlighted".

Comment: Actually I'm a little new with regards to using the google maps and GIS in general.  These polygons are actually user inputted, and are stored in the database and I output them with color and borderline. Thanks for the suggestion, I never considered doing it like that! As for turning polygons into grayscale bitmap, how will I be able to do this programatically?Will this be achievable in google maps? Sorry for the ignorance haha

Comment: I actually use google maps' google.map.polygons to output the polygons and store the polygons' vertices into my database.  So my question is how I would be able to turn these into grayscale bitmap?

Comment: The details of the process depend on the programming language you are using. In JS, you'd use a `canvas` element to draw the polygons, in Java you'd use a `BufferedImage` (`getGraphics()` to draw to it, `getRGB` to read the pixels)

Comment: i actually used google api polygon for this, which is also done using javascript, if ever it were javascript.  Do you have an example of this method being implemented in javascript?